# Blackbird logger - absolutely nothing happens

Tags: javascript

This should be so simple...

I thought it would be nice to try the Blackbird logger ([Blackbird home page](http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/))

Following the guide on the authors page, I created a directory on the server and loaded blackbird.js, blackbird.css, the two blackbird image files and a .html file containing the following into the directory.  When I access the page, the alert fires but absolutely nothing else happens.  The blackbird .js and .css files are loading and visible in a debugger.
Where have I gone wrong?  (same result on Firefox, Chrome and IE).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Blackbird test</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blackbird.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="blackbird.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function func1() {
            alert("In function, about to send log messages");
            log.debug("hello");
            log.debug( 'this is a debug message' );
            log.info( 'this is an info message' );
            log.warn( 'this is a warning message' );
            log.error( 'this is an error message' );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="func1();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, just verified.  No errors in Firebug console and blackbird.js is visible in firebug script tab and blackbird.css is visible in firebug css tab.  I'm mystified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to explicitly tell blackbird to appear:

```
function func1() {
    log.toggle(); // Show it
    // rest of your code here;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  The sample code on the developers website mentions the toggle() function but doesn't show it in the example code.